# How can I find the total number of users?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm looking for a way to get the total number of users in Django. My best guess would be something like:

**models.py**

```
def homepage_view(request):
    context = {
        "users": Users.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/index.html', context=context)
```

**html**

```
{{users.count}}
```

I don't know how to import all the users to my view

Comment: please, add detail information on your question.

Comment: I've updated my question with more detail

Comment: As you are saying, "I don't know how to import all the users to my view". So, what is your actual question? finding total number of user or import all users?

Comment: @Hasan It was both but it's solved now thank you

Comment: Just a note, you can skip the `all()`: `User.objects.count()`.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Thank you that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by importing users with

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Answer (score 0):

I am using a custom template tags to show the total number of users registered to my blog.

blog_tags.py

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, Value
from ..models import Post

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def total_users():
    return User.objects.count()
```

index.html

```
{% load blog_tags %}

<h4 class="pb-4">Total users: {% total_users %}</h4>
```

For further reference on how to [create custom template tags](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/create-custom-template-tags-and-filters-in-django)